# Reorganize the list of webs for Foswiki

Tags: foswiki

I'd like to modify and restructure the list of webs of a wiki based on Foswiki.
Is it possible to point me to a documentation explaining how webs can be transformed
into topics so that those would then disappear from the sidebar
while retaining the global wiki tree hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad. You can obtain a list of webs with the WEBLIST macro: https://foswiki.org/System/VarWEBLIST

You can format that list as per the documentation.

Or manipulate the list with the FORMATLIST macro provided with the FilterPlugin.

Removing a sidebar is an entirely different question. The answer depends on the skin you are using. For instance: In the default pattern skin you can remove the sidebar using the instruction in:
https://foswiki.org/System/PatternSkinCssCookbookNoLeftBar

Other skins would use different mechanisms.